# Pass data from a class to a template

Tags: php

I don't know how to pass data from a class to one of my class to the `studentShow` template file.

**MODEL**

```
<?php
class Student{
public function all(){
    require_once('config/db.php');
    $SQLCommand = "SELECT * FROM people";
    $Query      = $conn->prepare($SQLCommand);
    $Query->execute();
    $rows       = $Query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    return $rows;
  }
}
?>
```

**index**

```
<?php 


require_once("app/Controller/StudentController.php");


$Student = new StudentController();
$Student->index();

?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php 


require_once("app/Student.php");

class StudentController{


public function index(){
    $Student = Student::all();
    include ('resource/studentShow.php');
  }
}

?>
```

My Question is: in my Controller how to pass that `$student` variable to studentShow.php.

Comment: Can you show us studentShow.php?

Comment: When you include/require a file, it can see the variables from the scop in which it was in included. In your case, the `StudentController::index()` method. Also, you apparently have no idea what MVC is. Just because in insist on calling some files like it will not make it an implementation of an architectural design pattern

Comment: OffCourse i know what MVC IS because i uses Laravel every day but knowing something and some algorithm is not enough for implementation that thing i think . and if you really wants to help somebody you can send him docs links or something like that not just say that "You know nothing and so on "

Comment: Laravel does not implement MVC architectural pattern. It's just a over-hyped Rails clone. Also, that reminds me: why is it that you do not understand how variable scopes work in PHP, while you have been "using laravel every day"?

Comment: and that is why  i want to try to implement mvc with php. be sure about that if i want to create a project i use laravel. but now for learning i would like to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to achieve that:

```
public function index() {
    $student = Student::all();
    extract(['student' => $student]);
    ob_start();
    include ('resource/studentShow.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Read more about [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php), [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) & [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: it seems this code can pass data to view because my Error of Unknown var destroyed by this code . but i cant see the data in view when i Wrote this in View <p>
 <?php 
  foreach ($student as $stu) {
   echo $stu->L_name;
  }
 ?>
</p>

Comment: Can you verify that there is some data in `$student` variable?

Comment: i have data in mySQL so if i wrote my Model Correctly i think there is some data in $student variable

Comment: Just verify it once by using `print_r($student);exit;`.

Comment: where i should write this print_r function exactly

Comment: Just after `$student = Student::all();`.

Comment: i verify that.yes i have data in Student variable

Comment: `$student` contains an object or array?

Comment: My Problem Solved thank you my friend . i just wrote that include before ob_start() and its works.

Comment: Can you write code here? So that I will update question.

Comment: Final code ; public function index(){
  $Student = Student::all();
  include ('resource/studentShow.php');
  ob_start();
  extract(['student'=>$Student]);
  return ob_get_clean();
 }

Comment: @Amirh_ba You need to run the extract **before** the include and the `ob_start()` also needs to be run before the include.